# Photoshop action - copy adjustment layer to other open documents

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

I like a good time saving action - but I can't figure out how to build one which would really help me save some time.

I regularly work with product photography, usaully about 8 angles per product. I work on one product at a time, with all angles of the product open.

Once retouched and colour matched, I would love an action that would copy my selected adjustment layers (containing colour correction) to all the other open documents.

I've tried the duplicating method - this still requires you to select which layer to copy to, and also the select previous/next document, but nothing quite works as I'd like.

Thanks, FillW

Comment: I should add, it's not always 8 angles, it can be less. If there are less than 8 and I use select next document and paste, it will return to document 1 and apply the adjustment layer for a second time.

Comment: Not possible with actions but possible to script. Although theres a easy workaround send the other image to your current document

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at that :)